# How to get response status from in dojo xhr

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to retrieve a response code from response header,

```
var xhrArgs = {
    url: "/cgi-bin/cgi.py",
    postData: {            
    },
    handleAs: "json",
    load: function (data, ioargs) {
        console.log(ioargs.xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    error: function (error) {}
};
dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

console.log(ioargs.xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); // How do I get response code out here?? Should I parse the string or is there any other way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `status`:

```
load: function (data, ioargs) {
     console.log("XHR returned HTTP status: " + ioargs.xhr.status);
}
```

Here is a [good example](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/xhrGet.html#example-7-dojo-xhrget-call-and-checking-the-xhr-status-code-in-error-handler).